# Why are NAN values being displayed after splitting a column

Tags: python, dataframe, split, multiple-columns

My data looks like below:
Area:                                         Num
217099001/217112002/217112003/217112005       200
047041005/047041001/047041004                 123

I am trying to split the Area col, however I am receivng NAN values

```
df1 = df[['Area','Num']]
df1['Area'] = (df1['Area'].str.split('/'))
df1.pop('Area')
```

Result:
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN

Query:
1) Why is NAN being displayed
2) How do I fix this

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce, based on the sample data you provided I get a series containing lists of numbers

Answer (score -1):

You are operating on a Series. The str attribute allows you split each item in the Series. Some items in the Series are NaN.